# How do I tell my regex to pick from an array of strings?

Tags: regex, ruby-on-rails-5, gsub

I'm using Rails 5.  I want to replace occurrences in a string of an arbitrary amount of numbers, an optional number of spaces, a token from an array of strings, an optinal number of spaces, and an arbitrary amount of numbers.  So for example, this would match my pattern ....

```
123 / 2221111
```

or this

```
 102849/222
```

so I thought my regular expression should be

```
re = /\d+[[:space:]]*[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}][[:space:]]*\d+/
```

but the following is matching something that does not fit the criteria ...

```
2.4.0 :015 > re = /\d+[[:space:]]*[#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}][[:space:]]*\d+/
 => /\d+[[:space:]]*[(?-mix:of|\/)][[:space:]]*\d+/
2.4.0 :016 > TOKENS
 => ["of", "/"]
2.4.0 :017 > name = "10F 2017"
 => "10F 2017"
2.4.0 :018 > name.gsub!(re, '#')
 => "#"
```

The string "10F 2017" does not contain any of the strings from my TOKENS array so right there things should fail.  How do I rewrite my regex so that it only matches what I want?

Comment: Dave, `[(?-mix:of|\/)]` matches a single char: `(`, a range from `?` to `m` (i.e. a lot of letters, all ASCII uppercase ones), `i`. etc. Delete the `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By enclosing the `#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}` into a character class, `[(?-mix:of|\/)]`, you made it match a single char: `(`, characters ranging from `?` to `m`, `i`, etc. The range between `?` and `m` matches:

[image]

And see [what parts of the string each part of your regex matches](http://rubular.com/r/X9XAZl9mKN):

[image]

So, `[(?-mix:of|\/)]` matched `F` in your input string.

You need to remove `[` and `]`:

```
re = /\d+[[:space:]]*#{Regexp.union(TOKENS)}[[:space:]]*\d+/
```

See the [Ruby demo](http://ideone.com/31oMg7)